# How to fix error with invalid literal - functions

Tags: python

I am getting a problem when I run my code.  "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'r'". Is it something to do with my file_open function?  Because before, I had the contents of the file_open function actually inside the read_data function. but as soon as I gave that stuff its own function (file_open) it gives me this error.

````
def get_filename():
    """Return the name of the student data file to be processed"""
    return "rainfalls2011.csv"

def file_open(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as datafile:
        data = datafile.readlines()    

def read_data(data):


    results, total_rainfall = [], 0  
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        month, num_days = int(columns[0]), int(columns[1])


        total_rainfall = sum([float(col) for col in columns[2:2 + num_days]])
        results.append((month, total_rainfall))


    return results


def print_month_totals(results):
    """Process the given csv file of rainfall data and print the
       monthly rainfall totals. input_csv_filename is the name of
       the input file, which is assumed to have the month number in
       column 1, the number of days in the month in column 2 and the
       floating point rainfalls (in mm) for each month in the remaining
       columns of the row.
    """

    print('Total rainfalls for each month')
    for (month, total_rainfall) in results:
        print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, total_rainfall))



def main():
    """The main function"""
    filename = get_filename()
    data = read_data(filename)
    print_month_totals(data)


main()```
````

Comment: You never call `file_open` and simply pass the *filename* to `read_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're not calling your `file_open` function anywhere.

2) Even if it was called, you're not returning anything from it. It's just declaring a local variable and exiting.

3) You're passing `filename` to `read_data` - which is expecting the lines from a file, but it's getting `rainfalls2011.csv`

4) When you iterate over the the filename, it gives you each character in the string 'rainfalls2011.csv'. So in the first iteration you have `line` as 'r'.

5) `int('r')` is not valid - it will throw the exception you're seeing.

Fixes:

- Make you `file_open` function return the data

```
def file_open(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as datafile:
        return datafile.readlines()
```

- Call `file_open` and pass its return value to `read_data`

```
def main():
    """The main function"""
    filename = get_filename()
    data = read_data(file_open(filename))
    print_month_totals(data)
```